# what permission is need to access to content page?

Tags: nodes, users

I have created a role and a user assigned to it. I want to give access to  '?q=admin/content/node' to this role to see all the contents of the site. what permission should I set for this role? I am using Drupal 6.26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the node module a user must have a role that is allowed for 'administer nodes'.

Comment: I've given 'administer nodes' permission. but no admin menu is shown to user. should I create a special menu for this user and pur this link inside it?

Comment: Yes definitely if you do not want to add more privileges to that role then create a manual link. otherwise 'access administration pages' will show links in navigation menu for administration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the 'Access the content overview page' permission ('Node' section on permissions page).

Comment: Tested with Drupal 7.34